# Theorem: A graph with $n^2+1$ vertices has a path of length $n$

Tags: graph-theory

Theorem:
G is a graph with $n^2+1$ vertices. There is a path of length $n$ either in G or in the complement graph of G.

How would you show this? Is there a more general theorem one must use?

Comment: Looks like a pigeonhole principal question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, in what way? What would be the containers and what would be the pigeons?

Comment: I thought maybe to make an $n^2+1$ by $n^2+1$ matrix, "writing" the vertices as the columns and rows. If say $v_1 , v_2$ are connected then we'll have 1, if not we'll have 0. But how would this constitute a path and how would the pigeonhole principle help us?

Comment: Well, first show the graph or it’s complement is connected. That’s pretty direct - if $C_1,C_2$ is a partition of the nodes so that there is no edge between $C_1,C_2$ then the complement graph contains a complete bipartite graph, and thus is connected.

Comment: Presumably you want a simple path - no node visited more than once? Or maybe just forbid re-using an edge?

Comment: Yes a simple path.

Comment: somehow I feel like this is connected to the classic pigeonhole problem that says if you have $n^2+1$ numbers in a sequence then there is either increasing  subsequence of length $n$, or a decreasing subsequence of length $n.$

Comment: This is a standard question in Ramsey theory for graphs: show that $R(P_{n+1},P_{n+1})\le n^2+1$. In fact $R(P_{n+1},K_{n+1})=n^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

- For any vertex $v \in V(G_{n^2+1})$,

  $deg_{G_{n^2+1}}(v)=d \Leftrightarrow deg_{\bar{G}_{n^2+1}}(v)=n^2-d$, since $G_n \cup\bar{G_n}=K_{n^2+1}$ and $deg_{G_{n^2+1}}(v) + deg_{\bar{G}_{n^2+1}}(v)=n^2$.

  Obviously $d \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n^2\}$.
- Now, we shall use the above result along with the theorem that if the minimum degree of a vertex in a graph $G$ is $\delta$, then $G$ has a path of length $\delta$, with the following proof:

  Let's consider one of the longest paths in $G$, namely $P=(v_0,v_1,\ldots, v_k)$, the length of the path is $k \geq 0$, with equality holding when we have $v_0=v_k$.

  Let's consider the end vertex $v_k$ from the path, obviously $deg(v_k)\geq \delta$.

  Also, let's convince ourselves that all the neighbors of $v_k$ must be on $P$, since if some neighbor $u$ was not on $P$, then we can always connect $v_k$ with $u$ and consider the path $P \cup {u}$, thereby increasing the length of the longest path $P$, a contradiction.

  Which means all of $deg(v_k) \geq \delta$ neighbors of $v_k$ must be present as vertices on the path $P \implies$ length of path $P$ is at least $\delta$.
- Let's say $v$ is the minimum-degree vertex in $G_{n^2+1}$.

  If $deg_{G_{n^2+1}}(v)=d \geq n$, then $G_{n^2+1}$ contains a path of length $n$ by the above theorem, we are done.

  Otherwise, if $deg_{G_{n^2+1}}(v)=d < n \implies deg_{\bar{G}_{n^2+1}}(v)=n^2-d > n^2-n \geq n$, for $n \geq 2$ and then $\bar{G}_{n^2+1}$ contains a path of length $n$ by the above theorem.

  Only trivial case that is left out is $n=1$, for which $G$ has $n^2+1=2$ vertices and obviously there will be an edge (i.e., a path of length $n=1$) in between them in either $G$ or $\bar{G}$, which competes the proof.

Comment: When you say "Otherwise", it seems clearer to say $d < n$ rather than $d \le n$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. From what I gather the theorem you've mentioned and linked to states that in the graph *all* the vertices have to have a minimal degree. But we could have a vertex with a degree of zero and another witha degree of zero in the complementary graph.

Comment: @SandipanDey I do not think they dispense with isolated vertices but give a proof by induction also taking into account the 0 case.

Also, after reading the proof again - I see a flaw in the implication that $v$ is the minimum of graph G then it is also the minimum in the complementary graph. It will in fact be the the of the the vertex which is the maximum of graph G.

Comment: @Cantor  Added a generic proof of the fact that if the minimum degree of a vertex in a graph G is δ, then G has a path of length δ,

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument based on induction that doesn't use degrees.

Claim: In any graph G with $\ge n^2+1$ vertices, there is a path of length $n$ either in G or in the complement graph of G.

Proof by induction on $n$. In the base case, $n=0$, there is at least one vertex, and there is a trivial path of length 0.

In the inductive case, since the graph has $n^2+1 = (n-1)^2 + 2(n-1) + 1 + 1 \ge (n-1)^2 + 1$ vertices, there is a path of length $n-1$ in either the graph or the complement. Removing these $n-1$ vertices, we have $(n-1)^2 + (n-1) + 1 + 1 \ge (n-1)^2 + 1$ remaining, and there is another path (in the graph or the complement) in the remaining vertices. Doing this a third time, we get a third path.

Of these three paths, assume WLOG that two are paths of the graph itself, rather than the complement. If there is an edge between a node in the first path and a node in the second, then by taking this edge and longer parts of the two preexisting paths starting at this edge, we can make a path of length at least $(n-1)/2 + (n-1)/2 + 1 = n$. If there are no edges between these paths, we can create a path in the complement of length $2n$.

Comment: That's a very nice and elegant proof.

Comment: What I think in the formulation what needs to be added is to change the theorem's formulation as to state that a graph with *at least* $n^2+1$ also has path of length $n$, for in your proof, in the induction step you used it on the same graph, not construing a subgraph of the exact number of vertices. Am I right?

Comment: @Cantor Right, I did state that it was at least $n^2+1$ in my claim. I guess I was just leaving it as implicit that the graphs I'm operating on are the induced subgraphs with the removal of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If $G=(V,E)$ is a graph of order $mn+1$, then either $G$ contains a path of length $n$, or else the complementary graph $\overline G$ contains a complete graph $K_{m+1}$. (I.e., the Ramsey number $R(P_{n+1},K_{m+1})\le mn+1$; in fact it's easy to see that equality holds.)

**Proof.** Let $H_1$ be a maximal path in $G$; thus the endvertices of $H_1$ have no neighbors in $V\setminus V(H_1)$. Having defined $H_1,\dots,H_k$, if $V\setminus(V(H_1)\cup\cdots\cup V(H_k))\ne\varnothing$, let $H_{k+1}$ be a maximal path in $G-(V(H_1)\cup\cdots\cup V(H_k))$.

If we assume that $G$ has no path of length $n$, then each path $H_i$ has at most $n$ vertices. Since $G$ has $mn+1$ vertices, we have defined at least $m+1$ vertex-disjoint paths $H_1,\dots,H_{m+1}$. Let $v_i$ be an endvertex of the path $H_i$. If $1\le i\lt j\le m+1$ then $v_i$ is not adjacent to $v_j$; if it were then $H_i$ would not have been maximal. Thus $\{v_1,\dots,v_{m+1}\}$ is an independent set in $G$ and a clique in $\overline G$. Q.E.D.

On the other hand $mK_n$, the union of $m$ disjoint copies of $K_n$, is a graph of order $mn$ which contains no path of length $n$ and whose complement contains no $K_{m+1}$. Thus the Ramsey number $R(P_{n+1},K_{m+1})$ is equal to $ mn+1$.

If you just want monochromatic paths, then $R(P_m,P_n)=n+\lceil m/2\rceil-1$ for $n\ge m\ge2$; see L. Gerencsér and A. Gyárfás, On Ramsey-type problems, *Ann. Univ. Sci. Budapest. Eötvös Sect. Math.* 10 (1967), 167-170 ([pdf](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Egyarfas/Cikkek/01_GerencserGyarfas_OnRamseyTypeProblems.pdf)).